# Difference between TokenUser and TokenOwner

Tags: windows, winapi, process

A process(-token) both has an owner and an user which can be retrieved with the winapi function [OpenProcessToken()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295(v=vs.85).aspx).

What is the difference between those two and when are they different?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the MSDN document that refers to the concepts of token owner and token user.

Comment: They don't have to be the same, google "windows impersonation".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: he's talking about the TokenOwner and TokenUser options to GetTokenInformation().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Access Tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The access token functions use the following structures to describe the parts of an access token.
> [...]
>   TOKEN_OWNER     The default owner SID for the security descriptors of new objects.
>   [...]
>   TOKEN_USER  The SID of the user associated with an access token.

The pages for the structures have more information:

- [TOKEN_OWNER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  > [A] structure representing a user who will become the owner of any objects created by a process using this access token.
- [TOKEN_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  > The TOKEN_USER structure identifies the user associated with an access token

---

Edited to add a clarification pointed out by [Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston)

> To clarify the second point, the user associated with the access token is the user whose logon credentials were used to generate the access token. So if you log in as user1 the access token that your programs run in will return user1's SID for TokenUser.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Updated to include your clarification.  If you'd prefer a different citation, or if you would prefer that I not just directly quote you, just let me know and I'll change it.